# Performance of Microsoft Unity Container

Tags: c#, web-services, performance, unity-container

I am reviewing a project that has used Microsoft Patterns and Practices Unity Container.

There is a single container with 40 registered types, an instance of the container is created for every web service call.

I am wondering:

- Is there a performance problem due to registering so many types?
- Could the unity container be shared between web service calls?

The web services are hosted in IIS.

Comment: What type of application are you hosting your webservices in? On both windows applications and in web applications you should be able to compose the container on applicaiton start

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please create the container and register all types during Application_Start. We've done this for around 200 + types in a large project (wcf and asp.net mvc) and have had no issues.

Thanks

Comment: Am I correctly understand that for case when new container instance is required for request than we need to call 'CreateChildContainer' for the "main" instance and use the created one?

Answer (score 12):

Unity caches all sorts of stuff under the hood the first time a resolve is done. This significantly improves performance on later resolve calls. If you create a new container on every request, you're throwing out those caches.

Keep the container around between requests.

Comment: Will this caching help for containers that created with 'CreateChildContainer' method too?

Comment: Child containers also do this caching, with some wrinkles. If you're using the child container for lifetime management (using HierarchicalLifetimeManager) but not otherwise configuring registrations in the child, then the cache information is actually stored in the parent container, so the child can be thrown away without trashing the cache. If you're configuring registrations in the child, the cache will be stored in the child and go away when the child is disposed / garbage collected.